# How to register a Numpy Array?

Tags: python, numpy, image-processing

I have a numpy array, which contains a set of 20 or so images (so it can be thought of as a tensor). I need to find the easiest way of registering this stack of images.

Is there a function with numpy where I can input a set of images (in the form of an array), and it will return me a stack (adding all borders needed etc..) where they are aligned? If not what is the easiest way of doing this?[image]

[image]

Comment: There is something like that in [`astropy`](https://image-registration.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

Comment: There's lots of ways to register an image, depending on the type of image (eg, the way you'd do this in astronomy is different than in google streetview)--do you have a specific technique in mind?

Comment: Yes a biological sample, an image is now included. What would you recommend for this type of image?

Comment: How much do images differ? Is the registration needed a translation only, a rigid transform, an affine transform, something more complex?

Comment: Do you want to register each image with the first one, or each image with the previous one in the stack (as in a time series)?

Comment: As a time series. I think an affine or rigid transform will do. The problem is, the actual image is not as bright as this , I am log scale when demonstrating the image ... the actual image is quite darker. problem is, for downstream application, I need the values to be the original, not the log. my previous attempts at this did not yield a good result with the original image (see update to question)

Comment: Please put these details in the question itself, these comments can be deleted easily. And explain what that new image is you added. Is that prior to log transformation? If log transformation is needed to find a good alignment, it should be easy to then apply the found transformation parameters to the original image. That is not an issue.